# How to get block and receipts data?

Tags: blockchain, rpc, api

Is there a way to get the entire block information and transaction receipts within the block all in one function/method?

Irwing Tello

Comment: It is possible to get the entire block information using the Moralis Block API. If you are ok with using API I can share an example of how you can do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This data can be fetched from the chain using just one single RPC, using the [Single Flight RPC Add-on of QuickNode Marketplace](https://marketplace.quicknode.com/add-on/single-flight-rpc).

First, enable the [Single Flight RPC Add-on](https://marketplace.quicknode.com/add-on/single-flight-rpc) on your QuickNode Ethereum RPC endpoint. Then you can use the following ethers v6 script:

```js
const ethers = require("ethers");
(async () => {
  const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider("QUICKNODE_EETHEREUM_RPC_URL");
  const network = await provider.send(
    "qn_getBlockWithReceipts",
    ["block_number_in_hex_starting_with_0x"]
  );
  console.log(JSON.stringify(network));
})();
```

*This Add-on has built-in retry logic, so even if your method call fails the first time, it'll retry until you get the output.*

The output will look like something like this:

```
{
   "id":1,
   "jsonrpc":"2.0",
   "result":{
      "block":{
         "baseFeePerGas":"0x4bbdd7c2d",
         "difficulty":"0x0",
         "extraData":"0x",
         "gasLimit":"0x1c9c380",
         "gasUsed":"0x1a7919",
         "hash":"0x5e93e511585b002a56a2afee7313c2578b5e98bc67835d9c9e3ef42dff9e3961",
         "logsBloom":"0x010500000000200000000",
         "miner":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
         "mixHash":"0x09c73612b8dccc0b126aa2276f8854ede7760f6d548938e58d4b1ca4bef01516",
         "nonce":"0x0000000000000000",
         "number":"0xf7d1ec",
         "parentHash":"0xb739eab5d2c9ebfe1716af26446e09a3c349f1d417269bf70196a19f47fcaa81",
         "receiptsRoot":"0x61980ee0a5e9bdb789624ce64640a64ea9895cabd44b744e7de92bf4994ee0d5",
         "sha3Uncles":"0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347",
         "size":"0x2391",
         "stateRoot":"0xb2d04d19837a20839e2fb07c9604677020b2798c3f27be2051b099944cf2b3b6",
         "timestamp":"0x63a47743",
         "totalDifficulty":"0xc70d815d562d3cfa955",
         "transactions":[
            {
               "accessList":null,
               "blockHash":"0x5e93e511585b002a56a2afee7313c2578b5e98bc67835d9c9e3ef42dff9e3961",
               "blockNumber":"0xf7d1ec",
               "chainId":"0x1",
               "from":"0x5041ed759dd4afc3a72b8192c143f72f4724081a",
               "gas":"0x668a0",
               "gasPrice":"0x87f91cd00",
               "hash":"0x8169c8ec321e6a3de3b6f5384cfede82e92cfe4a8494cb3f5460213cb920d955",
               "input":"0xa9059cbb00000000000013185de0",
               "maxFeePerGas":"",
               "maxPriorityFeePerGas":"",
               "nonce":"0x14a02f",
               "r":"0x972cc5d000dd64ffb6ad46e77f49956bf717346b4d737e03b74f8dd39c72e867",
               "s":"0x68076e50ae03e870e6970a3228e92a9e4edb17d3e1bff903ea4eb0777cc25f5f",
               "to":"0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48",
               "transactionIndex":"0x0",
               "type":"0x0",
               "v":"0x26",
               "value":"0x0"
            },
            "...."
         }
      },
      "transactionsRoot":"0xcd2c9b517771b7edf621f92a2f85e9178fbf45319917db199bb3117c3797973e",
      "uncles":[
         
      ]
   },
   "receipts":[
      {
         "blockHash":"0x5e93e511585b002a56a2afee7313c2578b5e98bc67835d9c9e3ef42dff9e3961",
         "blockNumber":"0xf7d1ec",
         "contractAddress":null,
         "cumulativeGasUsed":"0x10059",
         "effectiveGasPrice":"0x87f91cd00",
         "from":"0x5041ed759dd4afc3a72b8192c143f72f4724081a",
         "gasUsed":"0x10059",
         "logs":[
            {
               "address":"0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48",
               "blockHash":"0x5e93e511585b002a56a2afee7313c2578b5e98bc67835d9c9e3ef42dff9e3961",
               "blockNumber":"0xf7d1ec",
               "data":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000013185de0",
               "logIndex":"0x0",
               "removed":false,
               "topics":[
                  "0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef",
                  "0x0000000000000000000000005041ed759dd4afc3a72b8192c143f72f4724081a",
                  "0x000000000000000000000000c82bc6286e1126b05e80eeeeee88af089beef27b"
               ],
               "transactionHash":"0x8169c8ec321e6a3de3b6f5384cfede82e92cfe4a8494cb3f5460213cb920d955",
               "transactionIndex":"0x0"
            }
         ],
         "logsBloom":"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000200008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002002000000000000000000000000000000000000000080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
         "status":"0x1",
         "to":"0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48",
         "transactionHash":"0x8169c8ec321e6a3de3b6f5384cfede82e92cfe4a8494cb3f5460213cb920d955",
         "transactionIndex":"0x0",
         "type":"0x0"
      },
      "...."
   }
}
```